# Print netplan config

Tags: netplan, stdout

Does netplan have any options available for writing how it interprets its config files to stdout, an arbitrary directory, or something similar?

The context for my question is that I'm updating a script which checks for common misconfigurations to support netplan. One of the things it does is determine what nameservers would be put into use if the system were rebooted or networking restarted. I know I could parse all of netplan's YAML files, and reproduce the logic for what priority multiple config files have, but I'm hoping not to reinvent the wheel.